# Excel VBA - Unable to find error causing 'runtime error 91'

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which is causing a

> runtime error 91 - Object Variable not set

I have dim'd each workbook, worksheet, and variable, but it does not remove the error.

```
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim snowq As Workbook, CAQual As Workbook, qsum As Worksheet, CAqsum As Worksheet
    For r = 2 To 8
        For c = 2 To 4
            combinedReports.Worksheets("combinedQualities").Cells(r, c).Value = _
                snowq.Worksheets("qsum").Cells(r, c).Value + CAQual.Worksheets("CAqsum").Cells(r, c).Value
        Next
    Next
```

NOTE that the first workbook and worksheet are dim'd further up in the code but within the same module.

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the top of the module which includes setting the actual workbook and worksheet(s):

```
'Create new workbook
Dim combinedReports As Workbook, combinedCsats As Worksheet, combinedQualities As Worksheet, combinedTickets As Worksheet
Set combinedReports = Workbooks.Add
Sheets("Sheet1").name = "Combined CSAT's"
Set combinedCsats = combinedReports.Sheets("Combined CSAT's")
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet2").name = "Combined Qualities"
Set combinedQualities = combinedReports.Sheets("Combined Qualities")
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet3").name = "Combined Tickets"
Set combinedTickets = combinedReports.Sheets("Combined Tickets")
```

Comment: You `Dim`'d something, but did not `Set` is to an object. For example, where is the line of code that starts with `Set snowq =` ?

Comment: Since that is a separate workbook, it is set there?  Should it (along with the other workbook and their associated sheets) be set here as well?

Comment: It has to be `Set` here after you `Dim` it- not in the other workbook, that's just not how it works.

Comment: Understood.  However, when I use the debug.print that @Variatus suggested below, it actually breaks on `Debug.Print combinedReports.Worksheets("combinedQualities").Name`, which is the workbook and worksheet that is the active workbook/worksheet

Comment: I dont see where you `Set` combinedReports either.

Comment: It is above this code.  I didn't include the entire code just so that it was less cluttered.  However, I have updated the OP to show the top of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this code before the `For r = 2 to 8` loop the code will stop on the faulty object.

```
Debug.Print combinedReports.Name
Debug.Print combinedReports.Worksheets("combinedQualities").Name
Debug.Print snowq.Name
Debug.Print snowq.Worksheets("qsum").Name
Debug.Print CAQual.Name
Debug.Print CAQual.Worksheets("CAqsum").Name
```

Comment: So it breaks on `Debug.Print combinedReports.Worksheets("combinedQualities").Name`.  Above the code I provided, I have some code that creates a table (formatting and whatnot), and above that I have the initial creation of the workbook and worksheet, which is where I dim'd the workbook (combinedReports) and worksheet (combinedQualities).  Do you think I need to "re-dim" them down in the code I provided to you?

Comment: Since the workbook `combinedReports` exists (as evidenced by the fact that its name was printed out) the culprit must be `Worksheeets("combinedQualities")`. Check the name. My guess is that the subject of the combination might be quantities rather than qualities. However, the test result identifies this sheet as the source of the error. Since it is referred to by name the error can't be in a variable or its declaration. It should be in the name itself.